# How to refresh contents of Fragment through its Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

What I currently have implemented the SliderMenu and its custom Adapter from:
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

However, I have modified the HomeFragment to have a few buttons, one of which creates a custom DialogBox. Once the Dialog appears, the user types in title and description of a Project class that is then being saved to an ArrayList in HomeFragment. The objects in this ArrayList get updated with this input data, but my HomeFragment does not display the input data. Currently I am trying to use getFragmentManager()...Transition...replace..commit routine and tried a number of other unsuccessful methods and it is giving me a NullPointerException. I am fairly new to Android developement, but I would like to figure out a method to pass this data to my MainActivity and then have it display a new View of the HomeFragment except with the new data from input displayed.

Here is the MainActivity:

```
//package and imports...etc.


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle=mDrawerTitle=getTitle();
    //load drawer menu items
    navMenuTitles=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
    //nav drawer icons from res
    navMenuIcons=getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems=new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    //adding nav drawer items to array
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));

    //RECYCLE
    navMenuIcons.recycle();
    //set the nav drawerlist adapter
    adapter=new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    //enable action bar app
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,//nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name,//nav drawer open - desc. for access
            R.string.app_name//nav drawer close - desc. for access      
    ){
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view){
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView){
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if(savedInstanceState==null){
        displayView(0);
    }

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem shareItem=(MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    ShareActionProvider mShare = (ShareActionProvider) shareItem.getActionProvider();
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    //shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text to share");
    mShare.setShareIntent(shareIntent);

    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }
    switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.action_settings:
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

//called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    boolean drawerOpen=mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title){
    mTitle=title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}
//using ActionBarDrawerToggle: call during onPostCreate() + onConfigurationChanged()
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private class SlideMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        displayView(position);
    }
}

private void displayView(int position){
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new ProjectsFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new PhotosFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new CommunityFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new PagesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new InfoFragment();
        break;
    default:
        break;  
    }

    if(fragment != null){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);     
    } else{
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

}

And here is the HomeFragment code:

```
//package and imports...etc.
```

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{

```
public ArrayList<Project> PL;
public ArrayList<Button> DB;
public ArrayList<TextView> TL;
public ArrayList<TextView> DL;
public Adapter adp;
public View rootView;
public HomeFragment(){
    PL=new ArrayList<Project>(3);
    DB=new ArrayList();
    TL=new ArrayList();
    DL=new ArrayList();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    final Button newProjectButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.new_project_button);
    DB.add((Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.first_delete_button));
    DB.add((Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.second_delete_button));
    DB.add((Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.third_delete_button));
    DB.add((Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fourth_delete_button));
    TL.add((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.first_tag_text));
    TL.add((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.second_tag_text));
    TL.add((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.third_tag_text));
    TL.add((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fourth_tag_text));
    DL.add((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.first_desc_text));
    DL.add((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.second_desc_text));
    DL.add((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.third_desc_text));
    DL.add((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fourth_desc_text));

    newProjectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        int i=0;
        public void onClick(View v){
            if(i<4){
                PL.add(newProject(rootView));
                upText(i, PL.get(i).getTitle(), PL.get(i).getDesc());
            }
            i++;
        }
    }); 
    DB.get(0).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            int i=0;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "firstDelete: "+PL.get(0).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            /* Do delete stuff here */
        }
    });
    DB.get(1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            int i=0;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "secondDelete: "+PL.get(1).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            /* do delete stuff here */
        }
    });
    DB.get(2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "thirdDelete"+PL.get(2).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            int i=0;
            /* do delete stuff here */
        }
    });
    DB.get(3).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "fourthDelete: "+PL.get(3).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            int i =0;
            /* do delete stuff here */
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

public void upText(int loc, String title, String desc){
    TL.get(loc).setText(PL.get(loc).getTitle());
    DL.get(loc).setText(PL.get(loc).getDesc());
    Refresh();
}

protected void Refresh() {
    Fragment f = new HomeFragment();
    FragmentManager FM = getFragmentManager();
    FM.beginTransaction().replace(this.getId(), f).commit();        
}

public Project newProject(View view){
    //create localized Project
    final Project P=new Project();
    //create DialogBox
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this.getActivity());
    //modify features BEFORE setting content view
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.project_dialog);
    //Create EditBoxes for Dialog
    final EditText titleEdit=(EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title_text);
    final EditText descEdit=(EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_description_text);
    //define button's text
    TextView text=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_create);
    text.setText("Create");
    Button createButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_create);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    createButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            P.setTitle(titleEdit.getText().toString());
            P.setDesc(descEdit.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Create button: "+P.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
    return P;
}
```

}

**EDIT**

Instead of using:

```
        Fragment f = new HomeFragment();
    FragmentManager FM = getFragmentManager();
    FM.beginTransaction().replace(this.getId(), f).commit();
```

I am now trying to use:

```
ListView list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
    ((BaseAdapter)list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Which doesn't give me a NullPointerException, but doesn't update the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `FragmentManager` to create a new transaction, you are effectively, tossing away the existing fragment, creating a new one, and then replacing the new one with the existing one. Naturally, the new fragment class does not contain the modified data and therefore displays new unmodified data.

Take a look at this line:

`Fragment f = new HomeFragment();`

You're just creating a brand new object.

After your dialog is dismissed, you should not perform any fragment transactions at all, instead just update the controls of the existing fragment to reflect the new data.

Comment: Now I'm trying to use:
ListView list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
  ((BaseAdapter)list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: In the upText method, get a reference to the Activity via this.getActivity() (you can cast it to MainActivity), then update navDrawerItems, and then use the notifyDataSetChanged() method. Right now, you are not changing the contents of navDrawerItems at all.

Comment: havn't tried updating navDrawerItems yet, but I messed with it a bit more and now the Table gets updated with items. However, when I switch from one view to another they get reset, any advice on what I can do to fix that?